# Multicolumn error: I expect to see \omit only after tab marks or the \cr of an alignment

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn, booktabs

I made the following table:

```
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{ABC} 
\label{tab:info}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.48\textwidth}{lX}
\scriptsize
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A Information} \\ \toprule
Attribute & Meaning\\ \midrule
\\  \hline \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{B Information}}\\ \toprule
\textbf{Attribute} & \textbf{Meaning}\\ \midrule
\\ \hline \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{C}}\\ \toprule
\textbf{Attribute} & \textbf{Meaning}\\ \midrule
\\ \hline \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{D}}\\ \toprule
\textbf{Attribute} & \textbf{Meaning}\\ \midrule
\\
\end{tabularx}
\vspace*{-0.8cm}
\end{table}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
I expect to see \omit only after tab marks or the \cr of an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
```

Comment: You can't put `\multicolumn` after `\scriptsize`. `\multicolumn` must be at the beginning of a cell (syntactically).

Comment: @F.Pantigny your suggestion resolved my problem. Kindly write it in an answer format so I could accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A command `\multicolumn` must syntactically be at the beginning of the cell. It can't be preceded by a token such as `\scriptsize`. The reason is that `\multicolumn` is expanded in a list of tokens beginning by `\omit` and such an `\omit` (which means : omit the format of the column specified for the current cell) must always be syntactically at the beginning of the cell (hence the error message of TeX).